# Getting "cannot commit when autocommit is enabled" exception while working with CachedRowSet in JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to implement a simple GUI application for working with database records. It would contain a view of records and possibility of editing them. Here is how my code looks like:

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    private CachedRowSet crs;
    private List<JTextField> fields = new LinkedList<>();

    MainPanel() {
        try {
            //Fill result set with data
            crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
            crs.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql:testdb");
            crs.setUsername("username");
            crs.setPassword("password");
            crs.setCommand("SELECT * FROM products");
            crs.execute();

            //Create text fields with labels
            ResultSetMetaData meta = crs.getMetaData();
            for (int a = 1; a <= meta.getColumnCount(); a++) {
                JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
                add(new JLabel(meta.getColumnLabel(a)));
                fields.add(field);
                add(field);
            }

            //Fill fields on startup
            crs.next();
            updateFields();

            //Buttons
            JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
            nextButton.addActionListener(...);
            add(nextButton);

            JButton prevButton = new JButton("Previous");
            prevButton.addActionListener(...);
            add(prevButton);

            JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save changes");
            saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    try {
                        for (int a=0; a<fields.size(); a++) {
                            crs.updateString(a+1, fields.get(a).getText());
                        }
                        crs.acceptChanges();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            add(saveButton);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updateFields() throws SQLException {
        for (int a = 0; a < fields.size(); a++) {
            fields.get(a).setText(crs.getString(a + 1).trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Walking next and previous works correctly. But I get an exception while trying to save records. The stack trace is following:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.commit(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:705)
    at com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetWriter.commit(CachedRowSetWriter.java:1396)
    at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.acceptChanges(CachedRowSetImpl.java:893)
    at test.MainPanel$3.actionPerformed(MainPanel.java:85)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    ...
```

How can I prevent this exception? What is auto commit? I know that Connection class has an option to set it to false, but I don't want to use the Connection class. I want to accomplish everything using CachedResultSet. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just add

`crs.getConnection ().setAutoCommit (false);`

Comment: My crs have no method getConnection()... I also don't create Connection object anywhere. I work directly on CachedRowSet.

Comment: you're creating a CachedRowSetImpl, which has a getConnection method - see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/rowset/com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl.html#getConnection%28%29).

Comment: You're right, I changed type and see getConnection() method. But when I call crs.getConnection() I get null. Why is it happening?

Comment: doesn't `RowSetInternal` mean that we shouldn't use it?

Comment: While running integration tests with postgres in IntelliJ (junit 4), I was commiting all queries because somehow autocommit was off by default. Then all of a sudden, I started getting `cannot commit when autocommit is enabled`, which means that autocommit got turned on, but I never changed any configs or parameters. I didn't even restart db's container in my local docker. What the hell

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the end of your [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator):

```
"?relaxAutoCommit=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue-- CachedRowSetImpl.acceptChanges() is failing to turn off autocommit, and when it goes to commit the changes an exception is thrown since they were already committed individually.

This may be because PostgreSQL is a little picky about autocommit. PostgreSQL does not permit turning off autocommit through SQL statements (although it did in its early days). Instead, any SQL statements that must be committed as a group have to be sandwiched between the SQL statements BEGIN and COMMIT. PostgreSQL's JDBC driver does support Connection.setAutoCommit(false), but I'll bet this merely prompts the driver to create a BEGIN-COMMIT sandwich behind the scenes.  My guess is that CachedRowSetImpl.acceptChanges() is trying to use SQL statements to turn off autocommit instead of using setAutoCommit(false) and that's why it is failing.

The only way I found to get around this problem was to create a temporary connection, turn autocommit off, and pass the connection to the one argument version of acceptChanges.  So instead of this:

```
crs.acceptChanges()
```

you would have something like this:

```
try (Connection con 
        = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    crs.acceptChanges(con);
}
```

This does require using the Connection class that you were trying to avoid, but there may not be any alternative (short of not using JDBC). You can't use CachedRowSetImpl.getConnection() because that only retrieves a connection that was created externally and then passed in. You can't specify through the url that you want autocommit to be off because PostgreSQL does not allow that. It would be great if CachedRowSetImpl.acceptChanges() could be updated so that it successfully turns off autocommit on its own. However, this seems somewhat unlikely given my compiler warns that CachedRowSetImpl may be removed in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues while working with CachedRowset. I am using the [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database.
while trying many solutions. I finally figured two workarounds which worked for me. I would like to mention them here:

1. Using the Connection object and pass them to the `execute(con)` and `acceptChanges(con)` methods. Also set `setAutoCommit(false)`.
   Example:

   ```
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, username, password);
   conn.setAutoCommit(false);
   CachedRowSet rowSet=new CachedRowSetImpl();
   rowSet.setCommand("SELECT * FROM tableName");
   int [] keys = {1};  // Set column 1 as the key column in the RowSet
   rowSet.setKeyColumns(keys);
   rowSet.execute(conn);  // Execute on connection
   rowSet.moveToInsertRow();
   rowSet.updateInt(1, 89);  // Use column number
   rowSet.updateString(2, "Programming");
   rowSet.updateInt(3, 77);
   rowSet.insertRow();
   // Need to move away from insert row before apply changes
   rowSet.moveToCurrentRow();
   // Reconnect to data source to apply change in the RowSet.
   rowSet.acceptChanges(conn);  // On non-autocommit Connection
   ```

Note: you don't need to set the properties of CachedRowset in this case like     `setURL()`,`setUser()` and `setPassword()`. Because the CachedRowset object uses  Connection object to connect to database which has been created manually and with  `autocommit=false`

2. Add `?relaxAutoCommit=true` to the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) as mentioned by [bobby-paulose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766484/bobby-paulose)

   ```
   Example:
   String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseName?relaxAutoCommit=true";
   ```